# Comparison operators not functioning as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, comparison

I have a set of checks to perform certain tasks.

```
// tempDouble is a (double), hour is an int

if (tempDouble > 60.0 && (hour >= 6 || hour <= 17)) { //CLEAR
    NSLog(@"CLEAR");
} 

else if (tempDouble > 60.0 && (hour < 6 || hour > 17)) { //NIGHT_CLEAR
    NSLog(@"NIGHT_CLEAR");
}

else if (tempDouble <= 60.0 && (hour >= 6 || hour <= 17)) { //CLOUDY
    NSLog(@"CLOUDY");
}

else if (tempDouble > 60.0 && (hour < 6 || hour > 17)) { //NIGHT_CLOUDY
    NSLog(@"NIGHT_CLOUDY"); 
}
```

When I have a temp of 76.3 and an hour of 2, for example, I'd expect it to jump to `NIGHT_CLEAR`, but it actually goes to `CLEAR`.  Did I set up my comparisons wrongly?

Thanks in advance for this simple question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(hour >= 6 || hour <= 17)
```

is always true.  All real numbers are either greater than or equal to 6 or less than or equal to 17 (some are both).  I think you want:

```
(hour >= 6 && hour <= 17)
```

The same also applies to CLOUDY.

Comment: Exactly, can't believe I didn't see that before!

Answer (score 1):

Some of your `||`'s might be better off being `&&`'s.

Perhaps what you want is...

```
if (tempDouble > 60.0 && (hour >= 6 && hour <= 17)) { //CLEAR
    NSLog(@"CLEAR");
} 

else if (tempDouble > 60.0 && (hour < 6 && hour > 17)) { //NIGHT_CLEAR
    NSLog(@"NIGHT_CLEAR");
}

else if (tempDouble <= 60.0 && (hour >= 6 || hour <= 17)) { //CLOUDY
    NSLog(@"CLOUDY");
}

else if (tempDouble > 60.0 && (hour < 6 || hour > 17)) { //NIGHT_CLOUDY
    NSLog(@"NIGHT_CLOUDY"); 
}
```

Comment: Careful with which ones you switch from `||` to `&&`. `( hour < 6 && hour > 17 )` is always false.

Comment: Besides what eldarerathis said, changing the first comparison to && fixed the problem.